# How to create a front facing SharePoint 2010 site ?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am a beginner in sharepoint 2010 development. I want to create a SharePoint 2010 site in which when anonymous user opens the site, it sees a normal site without the default controls like 'site actions'. but when a corporate user opens the site, it gets to see the basic sharepoint site with all the default controls according to his level of authorization.